# associative Yang-Baxter on U(g)

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra

Consider $\mathfrak{g}$ a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over the field $\textbf{k}$.
If A is an associative algebra, we are searching for functions from $\textbf{C}\times \textbf{C}$ to  $A\otimes A$ such that:
$$r^{12}(-u',v)r^{13}(u+u',v+v')-r^{23}(u+u',v')r^{23}(u,v)+r^{13}(u,v+v')r^{23}(u',v')=0$$
For $u,u',v,v'\in\mathbb{C}$. 
This is known as the *associative Yang-Baxter* equation with spectral parameters. 
Has the set of the solutions been unravelled when $A=U(\mathfrak{g})$ is the universal envelopping algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$?
In fact, I am searching for solutions which have the following *unitarity condition*:
$$r^{12}(x,y)=-r^{21}(-x,-y)$$

Comment: What is the relation between $A$ and $g$?

Comment: I reformulated a bit the question accordingly to your comment. I hope bob would agree with the changes I made. 

Comment: bob: If you register an account, it will be easier to edit your own question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about full classification results for $U(\mathfrak{g})$ in general (this is probably out of reach), but there are a bunch of very interesting constructions (together with partial classification resultas) when $A=M_n(\textbf{k})$ and/or when $\mathfrak{g}$ is a semi-simple Lie algebra:

- in the work of Travis Schedler: see e.g. http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212258 (this is very much in the spirit of Belavin-Drinfeld classification of solutions of the classical Yang-Baxter equation for a semi=simple $\mathfrak{g}$)
- in the work of Igor Burban: see e.g. http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~burban/AYBEnewsemistable.pdf (imo, this is beautiful geometric approach).
- in the original work of Alexander Polishchuk: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0008156

Comment: Ah, so it is ASSOCIATIVE YBE (not standard YBE) introduced by Polishchuk and Aguiar... Thanks for references...